Using Webhook URL in Azure Pipeline to send Microsoft Teams Notification
I had built a pipeline which scans the Keyvaults and sends a Microsoft Teams notification using Webhook(Eonos Office Webhook) incase any Key/Certificate has expired/about to Expire.
And the pipeline works perfectly, however since O365 connectors are deing depreciated, I am forced to use Microsoft Workflows to post a message from a Webhook Request.
For that I created a Workflow which 'Post to a channel when a webhook request is received' but when I replaced my current Eonos WebhookURL with the new Workflow URL, I am getting the following error:

this is the current configuration of the Workflow:

And this is my powershell function which sends the notification using the WebhookURL:

What I understand is that it needs a SAS token for authentification(maybe I am wrong) but I am not able to find a solution where/if a token needs to be generated or what needs to be integrated to send the notification successfully.
Update 27.08.2024
This is my updated configuration:


Hi there, Do you think this issue was related to the pipeline agent environment? Have your tried to Post the same $messageJson to that $WebhookURL via local PowerShell? Is the issue reproducible? It would be helpful to isolate the root cause. Thx.

By the way, which command had incurred this issue. Have you tried to print the variable values to check if the contents in $messageJson were valid and if the $message had expected value?

Based on your description, I am able to invoke the sample Power AutoMate WebHook request in a pwsh task of Azure DevOps pipeline.



pool: # server
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- pwsh: |
    $WebhookURL = "https://prod-xx.southeastasia.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/xxxxxx/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2ftriggers%2fmanual%2frun&sv=1.0&sig=xxxxxx"
    $messageParts = @(
      "123"
      "xyz"
    )
    $keyVault = "MyKeyVault"
    $message = @{
      'text' = ($messageParts -join "<br /><br />")
      'title' = "Key Vault: $keyVault"
    }
    $messageJson = $message | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 2
    Write-Host $messageJson

    Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $WebhookURL -Body $messageJson -ContentType 'application/json'

Please print those variables to double check if your pipeline had processed the expected values in $message, $keyVault  and $messageJson.

In case the error was caused by other script snippet, please share the relevant commands to investigate further.
Besides, since you should be able to execute that script anywhere with the command tool sets, you may try to run it in local PowerShell prompt before integrating it in pipelines. It is easier to troubleshoot.

Thanks for your reply. I printed out the values of $message, $keyVault and $messageJson and this is my output:

Debug: Key Vault: testkv
Debug: Message: System.Collections.Hashtable
Debug: Message JSON: {
"text": "The following secrets have no expiry date:Secret ID: [https://testkv.vault.azure.net/secrets/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxExpiry Date: 01/01/2023 10:10:00",
"title": "Key Vault: testkv"
}

I had called the Send-Notification function and the following command should have caused the error:
Send-Notification -keyVault $keyVault -WebhookURL $WebhookURL -messageParts @($expiringSecretsMessage, $noExpirySecretsMessage, $expiringCertificatesMessage, $noExpiryCertificatesMessage)

is your configuration of the Workflow same as mine?

Yes. My test workflow only contains the two actions to Get triggered -> Post message. Have you tried to run the Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $WebhookURL -Body $messageJson -ContentType 'application/json' command directly?

I tested your Powershell task with my Webhook URL and I am getting the same error saying:
"error": {     "code": "DirectApiAuthorizationRequired",
| "message": "The request must be authenticated only by Shared Access
| scheme."
Do you know why is it? or maybe can you tell me more about your Workflow Configuration?

Sure. I will share my sample workflow in the answer shortly. By the way did you observed the workflow triggered and failed in the second action to send message or the workflow was not triggered at all?

Thanks for sharing your workflow, I have updated my workflow like yours and attached a screenshot on my question(see above). I am still getting the same error saying "message": "The request must be authenticated only by Shared Access scheme."
did you make any other changes in your workflow? also, how were you able to add title as a dynamic contnt in the message box of the workflow? i just found 'text'. I think my problem is with the AuthToken, can you please tell me how did you configure yours? Thanks in Advance :)

I am afraid the issue was not related to the AuthToken. I can trigger the workflow without adding that information in my webhook request headers and messages.

My workflow could even be triggered, if I simply added those two actions with their default value/empty value. Even I didn't add the second action to send message, the first action to monitor the incoming webhook request should be able to trigger the workflow. That was why I suspected that your webhook request was not even sent successfully and never reached to the webhook listener and never triggered the webhook workflow.

ok I understand. When i try to test the Flow manually using the Test option in Power Automate, I am getting an error saying:  The Flow "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" cannot be installed.
Does that say anything about the problem?

I am afraid it was irrelevant as well. I could also reproduce the issue saying The Flow "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" cannot be installed as I didn't know what to input in the type or attachments fields when manually testing the flow. Still my payload was able to trigger the flow though.

Have you tried to run script with hardcoded webhookURL and body in local PowerShell?

Just pass a dummy json body like {"title":"123","text":"xyz"}

is it safe to use an external WebhookURL?

I thought I was the one who was taking risks. Anyway, you may opt not to send request to my listener. I will just remove it from my workflow.

Just want to rule out the issue by the webhook trigger.

Still you can try to run script with hardcoded webhookURL and body like {"title":"123","text":"xyz"} in local PowerShell.

I am sorry, I just tried with your Webhook URL and it didnt show any error. Does this mean that my URL is being blocked by something?

Yes. I can see my flow was triggered with the payload {   "title": "Key Vault: MyKeyVault",   "text": "123<br /><br />xyz" }. So we can narrow down the issue to your specific webhook URL? I simple copied out the URL from the When a Teams webhook request is received action. Would you check the Microsoft Teams connection status referenced by this workflow or create a new one for this work for a test? I shared some screenshots on the settings in my answer.

Zhao Sorry for the late reply, but I found the problem. When I created directly in the Teams Channel and not through the Microsoft Teams, then the Webhook URL worked and I recieved the Notification in the Teams Channel. Thank you very much for your help and time! :)
